# Javascript regex match for certain websites only

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I'm not really good with regular expressions, so I'm hoping someone could help come up with something that would fit what I'm trying to do, which is:

I want it to match in the following cases (only for youtube links):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
http://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0
www.youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0
youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0

also in the first three examples, it should match any domain ending, so not just .com

While I'm asking this, I will also need to be able to get the video ID alone as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
function getYoutubeId(str) {
    var check;
    check = /youtu.be\/(\w+)/.exec(str); 
    if(check) return check[1];
    check = /youtube\.com\/.*v=(\w+)/.exec(str); 
    if(check) return check[1];
    return null;
}

getYoutubeId("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0
getYoutubeId("www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0
getYoutubeId("youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0
getYoutubeId("http://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0
getYoutubeId("www.youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0
getYoutubeId("youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0"); // oHg5SJYRHA0

getYoutubeId(""); // null
getYoutubeId("google.com"); // null
getYoutubeId("youtu.be/"); // null
getYoutubeId("youtube.com/?other=something"); // null
```

Comment: Never thought of doing them like that, that's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be.com)/(?:watch\?v=)?([\d\w]+)
```

The first captured group is the video id. You can test it here: http://www.regexr.com.